# Emotion.js with create-react-app: ReferenceError: jsx is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, emotion

I am trying to use emotion.js with create-react-app and TypeScript.
Following the [documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) I added `@emotion/core`, used `import {jsx, css} from '@emotion/core';` and added `/** @jsx jsx */` at the top of my file.

But when I am running the app, the following error gets thrown:

`ReferenceError: jsx is not defined`

This is my example component:

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import {jsx, css} from '@emotion/core';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationBar} from "./NavigationBar";

export const Header: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
  <div css={{
    backgroundColor: 'hotpink',
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'lightgreen'
    }
  }}>
    <NavigationBar/>
    Test
  </div>
);
```

The line, the error gets thrown at is the definition of the function: `export const Header: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (`

Any help how to get this to work (other than ejecting create-react-app scripts) would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a known issue https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1112

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Emotion should work right out of the box now according to this [comment](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1112#issuecomment-460545525) on github.

The solution is to put a `jsx;` statement somewhere in the file, like so:

```
/** @jsx jsx */

import {jsx, css} from '@emotion/core';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationBar} from "./NavigationBar";

jsx;

export const Header: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
  <div css={{
    backgroundColor: 'hotpink',
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'lightgreen'
    }
  }}>
    <NavigationBar/>
    Test
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but this is exactly what I have been doing as well. 

Related: https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/9095

Answer (score 1):

To add to Johannes Klauß's answer, you don't need to reference `jsx;`

You just need the pragma statement (top-line and import):

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { jsx } from "theme-ui"
```

Example:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import {jsx, css} from '@emotion/core';
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationBar} from "./NavigationBar";


export const Header: React.FunctionComponent<{}> = () => (
  <div css={{
    backgroundColor: 'hotpink',
    '&:hover': {
      color: 'lightgreen'
    }
  }}>
    <NavigationBar/>
    Test
  </div>
);
```

you may need to add:

```
/** @jsxRuntime classic */
```

as well if using theme-ui and next.JS